# Is it possible to control a remote terminal window?

Tags: ssh, terminal, remote-access, remote-control

I run a few things in a terminal window at work (osx and linux servers) and would often like to check on them from home.  I can ssh to my work computer, but I'm wondering if it's possible to control the remote terminal window through ssh or otherwise.  I've used vnc to connect to my work mac but my home internet drags in that case. A text solution would be preferred.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you can SSH to your work computer, why not use screen in linux to connect back to your sessions at work?

For example:

You're running a job on your linux server at work via SSH from your desktop at work. If you worked inside a screen session, you could simply SSH into your work computer, and use screen to pick up where you left off.

Next time you're at work, before you SSH anywhere, run this:

```
screen
```

You can then do a:

```
CTRL+A C
```

To create new screens, and SSH to other linux or OSX servers. When you're at home, ssh back into your work machine, and do a:

```
screen -x
```

To connect back to your screen session. It will look exactly like it did at work, and it will be all text based.

For more information on screen see:

http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_screen

Or use the man page:

```
man screen
```

Comment: Very cool. Thanks.  I haven't tried it from home, but i tested at work by sshing back to my computer from a server.

Comment: Welcome! I love screen, its useful for so many things, and has a lot of options. Have fun!